# how do i make my onchange function generic?

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

My Javascript function checks for radio button selection and displays the appropriate drop down box. but this code is not generic, i tried using "this" but it doesn't help.. can this actually be generic?

**CODE:**

```
function change(s)
{
if(document.getElementById("viewstate").checked==true)
{
    document.getElementById("state").style.display="inline";
    document.getElementById("cat").style.display="none";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("state").style.display="none";
    if(document.getElementById("viewcat").checked==true)
    {
        document.getElementById("cat").style.display="inline";
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("cat").style.display="none";
}
}
```

**Front end radio button**

```
<input type="radio" name="viewrecord" value="viewstate" onchange="change('state')" required="" id="viewstate"> View by State

<select name="stat" id="state" style="display:none;">
<option selected disabled>Select State</option>

<input type="radio" name="viewrecord" value="viewcat" required="" onchange="change('cat')" id="viewcat">View By Agency
<select id="cat" name="che" style="display:none" required="">
```

Comment: how exactly do you define "generic"?

Comment: Everything working fine. What you want? https://jsfiddle.net/ynu4aa8s/ ?

Comment: The `s` parameter in your function is not being used, is this part of the "generic" part you want to add ?

Comment: Everything works fine... but it's specific. I need to manually give the ID of the drop downs to make it inline/none... @estebanrincon , yes previous version of my program used generic version and s was the ID given .. but at the previous version, if the radio box is unselected, it doesn't disappear...so i changed to this new specific version

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this snippet

JS

```
      document.addEventListener('click',function(event){
       var tar = event.target.id;
        if(tar ==="viewstate"){
           document.getElementById("state").style.display="inline";
           document.getElementById("cat").style.display="none";
        }
        else if(tar==="viewcat"){
           document.getElementById("state").style.display="none";
           document.getElementById("cat").style.display="inline";

        }
    },false)
```

[WORKING COPY](https://jsfiddle.net/76pmzg7b/)

What else I tried?

My primary idea was to add a class to next select tag. For example if you select `radio#viewstate` it will add a class to closest select element. Then just loop through all the select tag and whoever dont have this class , hide them.
But since you are using `display:none` `nextSibling` will not work.For why `nextSibling` wont work you can take a look at difference between it `visibility:hidden`

Also note in the demo that I have used `label` tag with input

Answer (score 0):

If by generic you mean to make the function to be able to work for any similar selection process without depending on the hard-coded values of the selection inputs, this is one way I thought of doing it :

```
function change(selectorId, selectorClass) {
  // Get all the selector elements you use.
  var rS = document.getElementsByClassName( selectorClass );

  // Out of the elements you fetched above, make the one with
  // id = selectorId visible, rest hidden.
  for(var i = 0; i < rS.length; ++i)
   rS[i].style.display = (rS[i].id == selectorId) ? "inline" : "none";
}
```

In the HTML part add a class to every select input you want to use with the radio values:

```
<input type="radio" name="viewrecord" value="viewstate" onchange="change('state', 'record-selector')" required="" id="viewstate"> View by State

<select class='record-selector' name="stat" id="state" style="display:none;">
<option selected disabled>Select State</option>

<input type="radio" name="viewrecord" value="viewcat" required="" onchange="change('cat', 'record-selector')" id="viewcat">View By Agency
<select class='record-selector' id="cat" name="che" style="display:none" required="">
```

With this you can use the same function for similar selection process on different forms.